# Using own map information including polygons in the solar API?

Tags: json, dashboard, orthographic, google-solar-api

We are a company that undertakes droneflights and performing flights for local communities. In an automated post processing process we define the polygons of the roofs and till now we processed the potential by ourself using AGISOFT and QGIS.
We intend now to implement the solar API in our dashboard, let the customer play around with the parameters, let them save the results and use the results including an .obj file for planning further the whole PV system.

Is it possible to use our own data (orthophoto, 3D textured models) with polygons as .json file as layer?

We didnt find a solution so far.

WE expect to use our own date for regions that are not available so far especially in Europe/Austria/mountain regions.